# which is the best way to make api call in swift Alamofire or default API Call given by swift

Tags: ios

Which way is most used by ios Developer Alamofire or default API Call by Swift

Comment: mostly uses Alamofire for  API calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It very much depends on personal preferences... I like Alamofire (and RxAlamofire) but I suggest that you give both implementations a go to find what you like the best.

Comment: I like Alamofire but is there any drawback of Alamofire which may affect my app

Comment: Not that I'm aware of